# After Joomla upgrading to Joomla 3.3 Front end not working

Tags: php, upgrade, joomla3.0, joomla3.3

I have upgraded Joomla 3.0.3 to Joomla 3.3. But after upgrading front-end is not working.
I have fixed the database using the backend.
I have set error reporting to development mode, but its not even showing any error. 
PHP version is 5.3.28
How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see a white page in php, it means a fatal error. Pls ensure that your php.ini has - -
display_errors=On
error_reporting=E_ALL

Alternatively in Joomla's index.php file you can put - -

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_ALL');
```

Let me know if still it does not work.

Comment: are you doing this on localhost? OR you are on a live web server ?